# Why are my header and main sections separated by white space?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a hero box but my herobox and navbar have white space inbetween. I can not get rid of it! I am guesing it has to do with flexbox and/or grid but i'm not sure.

I colored the nav purple and the herobox blue to try to figure why they don't follow each other. I tried messing with the margin and display in CSS.

Chrome inspection of elements:

[image]

My code so far:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  margin-top: none;
}


/*NAVIGATION BAR*/

header {
  height: fit-content;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

.left {
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.right {
  padding: 20px;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .left,
  .right {
    width: 100%;
    /* The width is 100%, when the viewport is 800px or smaller */
  }
}


/*HERO BOX*/

.hero {
  background-color: aqua;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 15vw;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <!--NAVIGATION BAR-->
  <nav>
    <div class="topnav">
      <div class="left">
        <a href="#Coupons">
          <p>Coupons!</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <a href="#Order">
          <p>Order Online!</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<main>
  <div class="hero">
    <h1>Super Restaurant!</h1>
    <button><a href="#menu">View our menu!</a></button>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

Set the `h1` to `margin-top: 0`.

### Explanation

The `h1` has a `margin-top` that is creating the space with the `header` section.

This is happening because, even though the `h1` is a descendant of the `main` element, its top margin is superseding the top margins of its ancestors (`.hero` and `main`).

And this is happening because of the rules of margin collapsing.

> **[§ 8.3.1 Collapsing margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html#collapsing-margins)**
>
> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or
> might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin.
>
> Margins that combine this way are said to collapse, and the resulting combined margin is called a collapsed margin.
>
> Adjoining vertical margins collapse, except [in certain cases].
>
> Horizontal margins never collapse.
>
> *The top margin of an in-flow block element collapses with its first*
> *in-flow block-level child's top margin if the element has no top*
> *border, no top padding, and the child has no clearance.*

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the margin top on the header is causing the problem. try giving it a margin of 0 and giving it padding if you need and see what happens

```
h1 {
  font-size: 15vw;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extra margin is from h1 (commented in code, info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)).
Useful snippet for making completely own styling:

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Removes all margins and padding and also makes all elements same box-sizing.

Also, for example, re-create **nav** using grid styles, try to avoid float in positioning of elements, its intended for positioning images in text or etc.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  margin-top: none;
}

/*NAVIGATION BAR*/

header {
  height: fit-content;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
}

.left {
  padding: 20px;
  place-self: center start;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.right {
  padding: 20px;
  place-self: center end;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .topnav{
    grid-template-columns:1fr;
  }
}

/*HERO BOX*/
.hero {
  background-color: aqua;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 15vw;
  margin-top:0; /* fix */
}
```

```html
<header>
    <!--NAVIGATION BAR-->
    <nav>
      <div class="topnav">
      <div class="left">
          <a href="#Coupons"><p>Coupons!</p></a>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
          <a href="#Order"><p>Order Online!</p></a>
      </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="hero">
      <h1>Super Restaurant!</h1>
      <button><a href="#menu">View our menu!</a></button>
    </div>
  </main>
```